# oauth2 flow using doorkeeper with chrome extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome-extension, doorkeeper

I have a chrome extension I want to use as an oauth2 client to my rails app using doorkeeper and devise.  In the extension I have

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
  {'url': 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/authorize?client_id=98c0af01eec1004144f32a6fd5d114b40efcd01771e24a7190f2acd06ac552c8&redirect_uri=https://galaiojniedmogfplghkjnmcfnlbpbpg.chromiumapp.org?response_type=code&scope=', 'interactive': true},
  function(redirect_url) { 
    /* Extract token from redirect_url */ 
    console.log(redirect_url)
  }
);
```

This launches a window which asks me to sign in with my rails application.  Upon signing in and closing this window the `console.log` is run, but `redirect_url` is `undefined`.

In doorkeeper admin my callback url for this client is `https://galaiojniedmogfplghkjnmcfnlbpbpg.chromiumapp.org/` which I retrieved by calling `chrome.identity.getRedirectUrl()`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You might want to check this [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples#_sample_github-auth) sample from [User Authentication](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) documentation. This show a google implementation sample of `launchWebAuthFlow`, making this as a base reference will help track why redirect_url is undefined. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with how I had doorkeeper setup.  Because I had session auth in front of the redirect it was returning a 301. Make sure your auth works outside of the chrome extension flow before hooking it up to the extension.